# Hiding an element while also backing up the layout

Tags: css, html, hidden

I have a script (JS) running that will be making some different divs either visible or hidden.  The problem I am having is that, even though the elements have a 'visibility' property of 'hidden', they still take up space.  Is there a way I can hid the elements while also preventing them from taking up space?

I have access to jQuery as well, if that means anything...

Cheers,

DalexL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for display none,

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `display: none` css property

when you use `visibility :hidden` the hidden element still occupies its height and width.
While display property make the element completely collapse.

Comment: Glad i could help, Here are all the values the [Display can take](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `display: none;` instead of `visibility: hidden`;

JQuery's `.hide()` method does this as well. You can display again using simply `.show()`

Answer (score 1):

You could either us jQuery's `hide()` function:

```
$("#sample").hide();
```

If you wanted to hide multiple divs, just add a class to all of them, and hide the entire class:

```
$(".sample").hide();
```

You could also use javascript like so:

```
function hidedivs() {
document.getElementById('sample').style.display='none';
}
```

But with that, you'd have to make one for each element. I'd recommend the above jquery.

More about `hide()` here: http://api.jquery.com/hide